# Sending large data sets. Best approach

Tags: javascript, mysql, socket.io, hapi.js

I use Hapi/React/Sequelize/MySQL stack
I have a client. And based on a request, server might send 1 or up to 500k results. Those results is an array with objects (maybe 15 properties per object). Sending large lists is not an option, since it takes much time an memory. I also need to do some calculation on the result set.
So I thought to send data in chunks, maybe 10k each (3 seconds).
I can think of two approaches.

Approach One (Long polling):

1. I make initial request on the server, and the server return me only id of the Products.
2. For example, I get 100k ids. Client sends AJAX requests in 10k chunks. Once it reaches 100k then it shows the results to the client.

Approach Two (Sockets):

1. Client makes request. Socket is opened.
2. Server sends chunks of 10k via socket.
   Can the socket handle that much traffic? 10k is approximately 300kb in size.

Is there another approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest parallel requests for every 10k or lower chunks then after  calculation it displays it's results while the rest still loads as it appends the main display and so on :)

```
EDIT: pseudocode
listOfProductsIDArray = get id of products;
itemsPerLoad = 10;
mainDisplay = array;
for loop (index = listOfProductsIDArray/itemsPerLoad ){

send AJAX request with index;
if(AJAXrequest is success)
       procees results
       mainDisplay appends results from mysql
}

mysql side::
select * from products limit AJAXindex,itemsPerload
return results
```

Comment: Might have an example? :)

Comment: Edited, and please leave a vote if it is accepted :)